# how to get rid of the synchronous error in my function for notification?

Tags: node.js, express

The following is my code to send an array of string into the views but the problem is that i think the rendering done before both the loops actually finish .Can you suggest me a way to solve it.I am very new to backend. I have applied to  a job named **qwjob** many times

```js
module.exports.profile2=function(req,res){
  let notif = [];
  User.findById(req.user._id)
    .populate('applied_jobs')//users has an array of applied jobs id
    .exec(function(err, user){
    for(a of user.applied_jobs){
      Job.findById(a._id)//finds the job according to ids present in the array
        .populate('applicants')//populates the apllicants
        .exec(function(err, job){
        for(a of job.applicants){           //loop for job applicants
          if(a.user == user.id && a.notification=="yes"){
          
            notif.push(job.title);//this doesnot seem to work ,however i feel that it is just done after the rendering is done
            console.log(job.title);//this is executed many times as i can see in my terminal.
            a.notification="no";
            
            console.log("yahan pe agae");//this is also shown in console 
          }
          
        }
        job.save();
      })
      
    }
    console.log("**********",notif.length);
    return res.render('user' ,{
      title: "User",
      notif: notif
    });
  })
  
}
```

**This is shown in my terminal**

```
********** 0
qwjob
yahan pe agae
qwjob
yahan pe agae
qwjob
yahan pe agae
qwjob
yahan pe agae
qwjob
yahan pe agae
qwjob
yahan pe agae
qwjob
yahan pe agae
qwjob
yahan pe agae
qwjob
yahan pe agae
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try rewriting your code a little to use javascript async/await keywords. This will let you run parts of your code synchronously.

You will probably need to update this line:

`await Applicant.update({_id: id}, {notification: "no"})`

As I'm not exactly sure what your `Applicant` model is actually named.

Here's full code:

```
module.exports.profile2 = async function (req, res) {
  let notif = []
  let user = await User.findById(req.user._id).populate('applied_jobs').exec()
  for (a of user.applied_jobs) {
    let job = await Job.findById(a._id).populate('applicants').exec()
    for (a of job.applicants) {
      if (a.user == user.id && a.notification == "yes") {
        notif.push(job.title)
        await Applicant.update({_id: id}, {notification: "no"})
      }
    }
  }
  return res.render('user', {
    title: "User",
    notif: notif
  })
}
```

Comment: then it will be inside first for loop and it will be rendered again and again!

Comment: Yes you're correct, have refactored for you now, please have another look @NitinGangwar